# Reactjs: unfocusing a button element using .blur()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

I'm having a little issue whilst learning react - I'd like to unfocus (a.k.a `blur()`) a button DOM element, but for some reason this isn't quite working.

I think the issue, from what I can read, is around the use of the reactstrap `Button` component:

```
<Button className={buttonClass} onClick={this.handleCopyToClipboardClick} ref={this.buttonBlurRef}>
  <div className="d-flex justify-content-between">
    <span></span>
    <span>{ this.state.hasCopiedToClipboard ? 'Copied to clipboard!' : this.state.buttonText }</span>
    <span><FontAwesomeIcon icon="copy" /></span>
  </div>
</Button>
```

I'm binding a ref on a component? I think this is why it's not working.

The `onClick` function is working, which I have included below. I've including some commented out code out of things I have tried - all of which break the `handleCopyToClipboardClick` function.

```
handleCopyToClipboardClick() {
  this.setState(state => ({
    hasCopiedToClipboard: !state.hasCopiedToClipboard
  }));

  // this.buttonBlurRef.current.blur(); <= This isn't working

  // this.buttonBlurRef.blur(); <= This isn't working either

  // this.refs.buttonBlurRef.current.blur(); <= Or this

  // this.refs.buttonBlurRef.blur(); <= Nor this... :'(

  setTimeout(
    function() {
      this.setState(state => ({
        hasCopiedToClipboard: !state.hasCopiedToClipboard
      }));
    }.bind(this),
    1500
  );
}
```

Here is my Component constructor as well:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.buttonBlurRef = React.createRef();

  this.state = {
    hasCopiedToClipboard: false,
  };

  this.handleCopyToClipboardClick = this.handleCopyToClipboardClick.bind(this);
}
```

Any advise on how I could potentially unfocus my Bootstrap `Button` would be great! :)

Answer (score 13):

You have an `activeElement` property in your document, so you could probably just call `document.activeElement.blur()` and it should work. You can also try to go other way around and instead of calling blur on your element- call focus on some other, like whole document for example: `window.focus()` or `document.body.focus()`. Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

I read on Reactstrap website that,

ref will only get you a reference to the Button component, use innerRef to get a reference to the DOM element (for things like focus management).

So, just replace  ref with innerRef on the Button Component.

https://reactstrap.github.io/components/buttons/

After getting reference of DOM element it can be blur by  this.buttonBlurRef.blur().

Hope this helps,

Cheers !!